# How to address multiple columns as one in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Columns `a`, `b` and `c` contain some values of the same nature. I need to select all the unique values. If I had just one column I'd use something like

SELECT DISTINCT `a` FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `a`;

but I need to treat `a`, `b` and `c` columns as one and gett all the unique values ever occurring among them.

As an example, let this be a CSV representation of `mytable`, the first row naming the columns:

```
a, b, c
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 4
5, 7, 1
```

The result of the query is to be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
```

UPDATE: I don't understand why do all of you suggest wrapping it in an extra `SELECT`? It seems to me that the answer is

```
(SELECT `a` AS `result` FROM `mytable`)
UNION (SELECT `b` FROM `mytable`)
UNION (SELECT `c` FROM `mytable`)
ORDER BY `result`;
```

isn't it?

Comment: could you add to your question an example output you want with table structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want one column all with unique values from a, b and c? Try this:

```
(select a as yourField from d1)
union
(select b from d2)
union
(select c from d3)
order by yourField desc
limit 5
```

Working [example](http://sqlize.com/S7U3nQj5XG)

Edited after requirements changed... There you have the `order by` and `limit` you requested. Of course, you'll get only 5 records in this example

Comment: op asks for unique result set not just unique results from columns. that will produce duplicate values.

Comment: no this will not produce duplicate.. union will give you distinct result set from all three column.

Comment: I'd also like to assign the resulting column an alias, sort and limit it. Where am I to put `AS`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in this case? I am also curious where can I put a semicolon(s) :-)

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx hope fully this will point you in right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html right now.

Comment: here is more link how it works.. http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Funtions-and-Operators/How-does-union-work-in-MySQL

Comment: @mosty i have tested your query, yes there aren't duplicate queries but result set isn't as op expected. there were 4 rows "1,2,3,4" for my example data set but it should be "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

Comment: There is a limit in the query. OP asked where to limit the query, so I provided the information. I also added a working example in the answer

Answer (score 6):

sorry i miss understood your question. here is updated query.

```
select a from my table
UNION
select b from my table
UNION
select c from my table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tmp.a
FROM 
(SELECT column_1 AS a
FROM table
UNION
SELECT column_2 AS a
FROM table
UNION
SELECT column_3 AS a
FROM table) AS tmp
ORDER BY `tmp`.`a` ASC
```

Comment: Do you mean this is going to produce different results?

Comment: @Ivan i have tested first versions of answers and there were different results but i think distinct is not necessary with my approach but you can implement easly order by and limit too to that

Comment: The manual says that I can put my `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to the end as far as I enclose individual `SELECT` clauses into parentheses ans that I can specify the alias with `AS` in the first `SELECT`.

Comment: @Ivan not sure what you want as result set. you may add an example result set to clarify that.

Comment: The example result is included in the question, isn't it?

Comment: I still wonder how is your query better than `SELECT a AS result FROM mytable) UNION (SELECT b FROM mytable) UNION (SELECT c FROM mytable) ORDER BY result` and why would I need to wrap it in the extra `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT b.iResult
FROM
    (SELECT a as iResult FROM tableName
        UNION
    SELECT b as iResult FROM tableName
        UNION
    SELECT c as iResult FROM tableName) b
ORDER BY b.iResult 
LIMIT BY 10 -- or put any number you want to limit.
```